Qiskit general amplitude embedding leads to long circuits
I am trying to use Qiskit to simulate many-body systems. Hence I calculate the ground state of Hamiltonians a lot. There are 2 ways I do them.
1: Calculate the ground state classically, then do state embedding using initialize(). This leads to very long circuits and uselessly noisy on the real backends.
2: VQE and get the ground state to be the last state vector which produced the lowest energy. This works for spin 1/2 pretty well. However, if the system is spin-1, I need to use more than 1 qubit to store the information of 1 spin. It gets messy. And the hamiltonian cannot be easily defined using the SparsePauliOp in standard Qiskit VQE tutorials.
Is spin-1 state embedding and hamiltonian calculations on quantum computers still a very open problem?
Share your thoughts! Any ideas are welcome!
